# How can we check whether the invitation sent already to the friend using facebook api multiuser selection friend dialog box by the user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there something in API , so that we can check that the invitation already sent to that particular friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the request is successfully sent the user will be redirected to

```
http://example.com/response?request=REQUEST_ID&to=ARRAY_OF_USER_IDS
```

And you will get the request ID and the array of the recipient user IDs for the request that was created.

If there are errors, the browser will redirect to

```
 http://example.com/response?error_code=ERROR_CODE&error_msg=ERROR_MSG
```

For reference checkout the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: Sorry , but no , its not redirected to that link because i am using Ajax and sending response to other page and getting success in the current page.